# Selling Lengths of Fabric in increments of 10cm

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am trying to build a Magento website that sells fabric. There are a few rules to this one:

- The fabric can be one of 4 different widths.
- The fabric is sold by length, in increments of 10cm.
- The minimum length of fabric is 50cm, the maximum length is 20m.

Can Magento 1.9 handle this? Will I need an extension to be able to sell fabric like this with Magento, and if so, what extension would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I think such situations can be handled by "[Custom options](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html)" functionality. So you can write a module or use something from Magento store,  There are some examples in Magento connect such us [this module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-options-pricing-dynamic-products-pricing.html).